# How to call Hashicorp Vault from AWS Lambda in NodeJS with IAM Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, hashicorp-vault

Does anyone know if there is a good NodeJS library to connect to hashicorp vault from an AWS Lambda using IAM Authentication.

Something similar to [HVAC](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) for Python would be good.

I have tried using [node-vault-client](https://github.com/namecheap/node-vault-client) but there aren't any good examples of IAM Authentication and it doesn't seem to have had an update since 2019 so I am not sure if its actively being maintained.

Comment: Won't this work https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashi-vault-js

Comment: You can see how to do it at https://github.com/namecheap/node-vault-client/blob/master/test/auth.iam.test.js. Note that with Lambda you would be unable to leverage the IAM instance profile, so you would need to pass credentials, which means you then have more secrets to manage (although could use Vault AWS engine with JS AWS SDK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working using [node-vault-client](https://github.com/namecheap/node-vault-client) but I had to make changes to the library because it doesnt allow you to pass a namespace header. I have raised a [PR](https://github.com/namecheap/node-vault-client/pull/23) that adds a new field to resolve the issue.

Here is a sample of my code:

```js
const VaultClient = require('node-vault-client');

const vaultClient = VaultClient.boot('main', {
  api: { url: 'https://my-vault-url.com' },
  auth: {
    type: 'iam',
    config: {
      role: 'my-role',
      iam_server_id_header_value: 'my-vault-url.com',
      namespace: 'my-namespace', // new option added in my pull request
      credentials: new AWS.Credentials({
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
      }),
    },
  },
});


 vaultClient
    .read('secrets/data/path/to/secret')
    .then((secrets: any) => {
      console.log(`MY SECRET IS ${secrets.__data.data['MY_SECRET_KEY']}`);
    })
    .catch((e: Error) => {
      console.error('Error connecting to vault .....');
      console.error(e);
    });
```

************ UPDATE **************

I have since decided to write the code to retrieve the secrets from vault myself and remove the dependency on node-vault-client.

First, I need to call AWS Secrets Manager to get the Vault CA Certificate

```js
// aws-secrets-manager.client.ts

import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import HttpException from '../errors/http.exception';

export default class AWSSecretsManagerClient {
  private static readonly client: AWS.SecretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  });

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
  private constructor() {}

  static async getSecret(secretName: string): Promise<string> {
    console.log(`Reading secret from aws secrets manager`);

    try {
      const response = await AWSSecretsManagerClient.client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }).promise();

      console.log(`Successfully read secret from aws secrets manager`);

      return response.SecretString;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Failed to read secret from aws secrets manager`);
      console.error(e);
      throw new HttpException('Internal Server Error', 500);
    }
  }
}
```

Then I authenticate with Vault to get an auth token:

```js
// vault-auth.client.ts

import * as https from 'https';

import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { Request } from 'aws4';
import * as aws4 from 'aws4';

import HttpException from '../errors/http.exception';
import VaultAuthResponse from '../models/vault/vault-auth-response.model';
import VaultAuthRequest from '../models/vault/vault-auth-request.model';

export default class VaultAuthClient {
  private readonly GET_CALLER_IDENTITY: string = 'Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15';

  async authenticate(caCert: string): Promise<string> {
    console.log(`Attempting to authenticate with vault`);

    const axiosConfig = {
      timeout: 5000,
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        ca: caCert,
      }),
      headers: {
        'X-Vault-Namespace': process.env.VAULT_NAMESPACE,
      },
    };

    const url: string = `${process.env.VAULT_URL}/v1/auth/aws/login`;
    const request = this.createVaultRequest();
  
    try {
      const vaultResponse: AxiosResponse<VaultAuthResponse> = await axios.post(url, request, axiosConfig);
  
      console.log(`Successfully authenticated with vault`);
      return vaultResponse.data.auth.client_token;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Failed to authenticate with vault`);
      console.error(e.stack);
      throw new HttpException('Internal Server Error', 500);
    }

   
  }

  private createSTSRequest(): Request {
    const credentials: AWS.Credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
    });

    const request = aws4.sign(
      {
        service: 'sts',
        method: 'POST',
        body: this.GET_CALLER_IDENTITY,
        headers: process.env.VAULT_HOST
          ? {
              'X-Vault-AWS-IAM-Server-ID': process.env.VAULT_HOST,
            }
          : {},
      },
      credentials,
    );

    return request;
  }

  private createVaultRequest() {
    const stsRequest: Request = this.createSTSRequest();

    const vaultAuthRequest: VaultAuthRequest = new VaultAuthRequest(
      stsRequest.method,
      encode(JSON.stringify(stsRequest.headers), 'base64'),
      encode(this.GET_CALLER_IDENTITY, 'base64'),
      encode(`https://${stsRequest.hostname}${stsRequest.path}`, 'base64'),
      vault.vaultRole,
    );

    return vaultAuthRequest;
  }
}
```

Then I call vault to get the Secret:

```js
import * as https from 'https';

import axios from 'axios';

import HttpException from '../errors/http.exception';

export default class VaultClient {
  private readonly VAULT_URL: string = `${process.env.VAULT_URL}/v1/secrets/data/${process.env.VAULT_ENV}`;

  async getVaultSecrets(token: string, caCert: string, path: string, key: string): Promise<string> {
    console.log(`Attempting to read secrets from vault`);

    const axiosConfig = {
      timeout: 5000,
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        ca: caCert,
      }),
      headers: {
        'X-Vault-Namespace': process.env.VAULT_NAMESPACE,
        'X-Vault-Token': token,
      },
    };

    try {
      const url: string = `${this.VAULT_URL}/${path}`;
      const {
        data: {
          data: { data },
        },
      } = await axios.get(url, axiosConfig);
      const secret = data[`${key}`];

      console.log(`Successfully read secret from vault`);

      return secret;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Failed to read secret from vault`);
      console.error(e.stack);

      throw new HttpException('Internal Server Error', 500);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// Get the Vault CA Cert
const vaultCaCert: string = await AWSSecretsManagerClient.getSecret(process.env.CA_CERT_SECRET_NAME);

// Get the Vault Auth Token
const token: string = await new VaultAuthClient().authenticate(caCert);

// Get the Secret
const secret: string = await new VaultClient().getVaultSecrets(token, caCert, 'path-to-secret', 'secret-name');
```